# mapping_msgs/CollisionObject.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, collision-object

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to add an object to my RVIZ scene, from this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/motion_planning_environment/Tutorials/Adding%20known%20objects%20to%20the%20collision%20environment#Adding_a_known_object_to_the_environment).

Would anyone know why using,

```
#include <mapping_msgs/CollisionObject.h>
```

would not be available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47607/mapping_msgs/collisionobject.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you are using Fuerte, it would be

```
#include "planning_environment/models/collision_models.h"
```

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-11-06**:
That should probably be included via <> and not "", since it isn't really a local header file and should be in a path specified with -I .

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-11-06**:
yes. it's my fault. it should be <>. you only need to add  in the manifest and ros will do the path finding thing for you.